# Extraer el valor de dos indicadores

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy nueva en python y estoy dando mis primeros pasos. Resulta que tengo un archivo de miles de filas. El contenido de los `string` que contiene cada fila puede ser de dos clases *(os dejo la captura de ambos tipo de string)* y viene determinado por un label llamado "mime" el cual puede ser video o audio.

Mi problema consiste en que no se como extraer el valor de las variables "lmt", "mime", "itag", "dur" prsentes en cada linea y al final almacenarlos en un archivo `.csv`.

He probado dividiendo y creando un nuevo archivo y usando vectores. Pero no llego a una solución *(me siento un tanto frustrada)*.

*String1:*

> Line 219 (6420),Dh,"          ""url"":
>   ""https://r3---sn-gxqpgpn-h5ql.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&requiressl=yes&gir=yes&pcm2cms=yes&ip=150.214.57.8&fvip=5&c=WEB&id=o-AKPE5P1-L_x8zzDRYj5aoX3bYJ1W02pyCMpEI4-dsRC-&gcr=es&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gxqpgpn-h5ql%2Csn-h5q7dnlk&signature=201841BEA18EE01EE5C51CEE1487A4CAC75DED51.0B35DB9CB1ADB52AFFF24A3250F9B1C5708068ED&keepalive=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&mt=1541693372&mv=m&initcwndbps=642500&ms=au%2Crdu&itag=251&mime=audio%2Fwebm&pl=16&expire=1541715093&clen=1853458&ei=NWDkW6LwLJic1waombfoBQ&key=yt6&source=youtube&dur=117.241&txp=5511222&lmt=1538050727946448&alr=yes&cpn=mH58o0Uz_dI7ZuKp&cver=2.20181106&range=309760-378453&rn=27&rbuf=5457"","

*String2:*

> Line 479 (106021),Dh,"          ""url"":
>   ""https://r3---sn-gxqpgpn-h5ql.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&requiressl=yes&gir=yes&pcm2cms=yes&ip=150.214.57.8&fvip=5&xtags=vproj%3Dmesh&c=WEB&id=o-AKPE5P1-L_x8zzDRYj5aoX3bYJ1W02pyCMpEI4-dsRC-&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C264%2C266%2C271%2C278%2C298%2C299%2C302%2C303%2C304%2C305%2C308%2C313%2C315&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gxqpgpn-h5ql%2Csn-h5q7dnlk&signature=369A4451CD5098765653E430D3FBFF20D4F8EF36.349B11C21BE7DEDFA4CA70F8365808EB9153FE4C&keepalive=yes&sparams=aitags%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cxtags%2Cexpire&mt=1541693372&mv=m&initcwndbps=642500&ms=au%2Crdu&itag=315&mime=video%2Fwebm&pl=16&gcr=es&expire=1541715093&clen=347859091&ei=NWDkW6LwLJic1waombfoBQ&key=yt6&source=youtube&dur=117.183&lmt=1492587801555590&alr=yes&cpn=mH58o0Uz_dI7ZuKp&cver=2.20181106&range=32056563-38295938&rn=28&rbuf=5553"","

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda. Al final lo que quiero es un archivo que contenga los siguientes datos de salida:

*Archivo .csv de salida:*

[image: archivo csv de salida]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que esto te podria servir:

```
ENTRADA = "test.csv"
SALIDA = "salida.csv"

with open(ENTRADA,'r') as e:
    for line in e: # lee cada línea del archivo

        b = line.split('&') # separa la línea por '&'
        c = {} # La idea es crear un diccionario con los elementos de interés

        for x in b:
            kv = x.split('=')

            if kv[0] in ['lmt','itag','dur']:
                c[kv[0]] = kv[1]
            elif kv[0] == 'mime': # en el caso de mime, el valor contiene un caracter '%'
                c[kv[0]] = kv[1].split('%')[0]

        with open(SALIDA,'a') as f:
            f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (c['lmt'], c['mime'], c['itag'], c['dur']))
```

Comment: tengo un unico archivo el cual se llama 'test.csv', este archivo esta en bruto solo separado por filas, cada fila contiene los indicadores que deseo extraer y grabar en un nuevo .csv.  Te pregunto porque no entiendo porque estoy confundida con el siginificado de 'a' y 'filename'.

Comment: Hola, he editado la respuesta aclarando un poco.

Comment: Hola @gustavovelascoh, muchisimas gracias. Lo he estado probando pero muchas veces me da el siguiente error, cuando hago el proceso con el archivo que contiene todos los datos.                                               File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (c['lmt'], c['mime'], c['itag'], c['dur']))
KeyError: 'itag'

Comment: Hola @Laura, ese error significa que no se encontró la variable `itag` (Al menos, de la forma como se está buscando). Es garantizado que cada línea la contiene o en caso de no encontrarla debería poner un valor por defecto?

Answer (score 0):

Hola mira se me ocurrió una función que puede ayudarte:

```
def buscarCadenas(cadena, nombre, largo, caracter):
#Extraer de la cadena el fragmento que coincida con el nombre pasado por parametro:
fragmento = cadena[cadena.find(nombre)+largo:len(cadena)]
resultado = ""
for x in fragmento:
    if x == caracter:
        break;
    else:
        resultado = resultado + x
return resultado
```

Lo que hace es pasar como parametros la cadena en donde buscar todos esos valores.
Los parametros "nombre","largo" y "caracter" corresponden a los datos que necesitas por eso varian en cada caso.

Este seria la forma de usar la funcion:

```
lmt = buscarCadenas(cadena,"lmt=", 4,"&")
mime = buscarCadenas(cadena,"mime=", 5,"%")
itag = buscarCadenas(cadena,"itag=", 5, "&")
dur = buscarCadenas(cadena,"dur=", 4, "&")
print("lmt: ", lmt)
print("mime: ", mime)
print("itag: ", itag)
print("dur: ", dur)
```

Espero te sirva :D

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
import re
data = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data =[ [re.findall('lmt=(.*?)&',x),re.findall('mime=(.*?)%',x),re.findall('itag=(.*?)&',x),re.findall('dur=(.*?)&',x)] for x in f.readlines() ] 

print("{:<18}|{:^10}|{:^10}|{:^10}".format("lmt","mime","itag","duracion"))
for x in data:
    print("{:<18}|{:^10}|{:^10}|{:^10}".format(x[0][0],x[1][0],x[2][0],x[3][0] ))
```